# React state access returns invalid state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Need some help to explain and perhaps debug and fix an issue with state.

My form has a control which implements google locations.

```
<AddressInput
    address={address || {}}
    onChange={value => onAddressChange(value)}
/>
```

```
const onAddressChange = (value: Address) => {
    console.log(state);
    const clone = {...state};
    clone.someOtherObject.address = value;
    setState(clone);
}
```

Yes I know I can do setState(prevState => ...). Thats not the issue here.

When onAddressChange console log is called and clone is made the entire state object other than someOtherObject has been reset to initial state. I can wait without doing any other action and still happens.

I also have

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state);
}, [state]);
```

which successfully prints out the state after other form-controls have been edited.
So before onAddressChange is called, the last print out from useEffect is different to what the state is inside onAddressChange and therefore after it the entire state is reset to some previous value.

This all makes me wonder if there is a condition I am not aware of that could make it so that for example on a button click that inits REST POST call, the state posted could be invalid.

---

Comment: Why `clone` is a `const` if you modify it? Much better `let clone = ...`

Comment: as I wont overwrite the entire clone I dont need to use let. 
const clone = ...; 
clone = ...;

Comment: It almost seems as if the initial state is associated to that particular form control and its onAddressChange method. It works with setState(prevState => ...) as intended, I would just like to know why the other option does not to be mindful of it in the future.

Comment: Anyway, what you are saying is quite unclear. `useEffect`'s log will print the very last `state` value. `onAddressChange`'s log should not be considered the very last state value (expecially if you work on chrome) because browser could decides to print out state after he changes (there are thousand of questions in SO about that). The intersting part for me is that you are shallow-cloning the state (and if I understood, you want to deeply cloning state because seems that it has nested object so spread operator doesn't work).

Comment: the useEffect only shows here that the state has been changed before I access it in the onAddressChange method. That do me says that the same changed state should be accessible in my onAddressChange method, which it is not. I would like to be able to understand and explain why this happens. I can use shallow cloning to edit some other value in a nested object and have not had issues with it so I don´t think thats the cause here.